# Add "real shannon wavelet" in matlab for continuous wavelet transform

Tags: matlab, signal-processing, wavelet

I am new to MATLAB and I want to do continuous wavelet transform with "Real Shannon wavelet" in MATLAB. Is there any way in MATLAB to add "Real Shannon Wavelet" to the wavemngr so I can simply do the CWT by using the function "cwt".

Answer (score 1):

It's described in the [wavelet manager documentation](http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/wavelet/ug/adding-your-own-wavelets.html). Besides that there seems to be already the Shannon wavelet to be implemented: 'shan'